# Is there a way to force Android Studio to use the second screen

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

Like most of the devs, I'm using a **dualscreen** to work.

Here's my question, is it possible to force **Android Studio** to open views (android layout, etc..) on the second screen ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can right-click over any of the dock points and choose "Floating Mode" to float that view as a separate window.

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do, I dragged my layouts to my 2nd screen but I'd like it to be automatic, specially when I use the feature to go to an view (like an Android Layout)